# spark scala - replace text if exists in list

Tags: scala, debugging, apache-spark

I have 2 datasets. 
One is a dataframe with a bunch of data, one column has comments (a string). 
The other is a list of words.

If a comment contains a word in the list, I want to replace the word in the comment with @@@@@ and return the comment in full with the replaced words.

Here's some sample data:

CommentSample.txt

```
1   A badword small town
2   "Love the truck, though rattle is annoying."
3   Love the paint!
4   
5   "Like that you added the ""oh badword2"" handle to passenger side."
6   "badword you. specific enough for you, badword3?"   
7   This car is a piece if badword2
```

ProfanitySample.txt

```
badword
badword2
badword3
```

Here's my code so far:

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

import sqlContext.implicits._

case class Response(UniqueID: Int, Comment: String)

val response = sc.textFile("file:/data/CommentSample.txt").map(_.split("\t")).filter(_.size == 2).map(r => Response(r(0).trim.toInt, r(1).trim.toString, r(10).trim.toInt)).toDF()

var profanity = sc.textFile("file:/data/ProfanitySample.txt").map(x => (x.toLowerCase())).toArray();

    def replaceProfanity(s: String): String = {
        val l = s.toLowerCase()
        val r = "@@@@@"
        if(profanity.contains(s))
            r
        else
            s
      }

    def processComment(s: String): String = {
        val commentWords = sc.parallelize(s.split(' '))
        commentWords.foreach(replaceProfanity)
        commentWords.collect().mkString(" ")
      }

    response.select(processComment("Comment")).show(100)
```

It compiles, it runs, but the words are not replaced.
I don't know how to debug in scala.
I'm totally new! This is my first project ever!

Many thanks for any pointers.
-M

Comment: After figuring out how to debug some by adding println commands, etc, I have found that the last line (which I've modified to: response.select(processComment(response("Comment").toString())).show(999)), only passes in the text "Comment". 
Well, that doesn't work....
How do I pass the column value?

Comment: @mvee: you can easily remove the profanity and replace it with nonsense words. Try 'foo' and 'bar'. It wouldn't change your question and you'd avoid carrying a lightning rod around.

Comment: ok, i'm new and completely sleep deprived. sorry. i've edited the post to remove the profanity. my bad.

Answer (score 1):

First, I think the usecase you describe here won't benefit much from the use of DataFrames - it's simpler to implement using RDDs only (DataFrames are mostly convenient when your transformations can easily be described using SQL, which isn't the case here).

So - here's a possible implementation using RDDs. This **assumes** the list of profanities isn't too large (i.e. up to ~thousands), so we can collect it into non-distributed memory. If that's not the case, a different approach (involving a join) might be needed.

```
case class Response(UniqueID: Int, Comment: String)

val mask = "@@@@@"

val responses: RDD[Response] = sc.textFile("file:/data/CommentSample.txt").map(_.split("\t")).filter(_.size == 2).map(r => Response(r(0).trim.toInt, r(1).trim))
val profanities: Array[String] = sc.textFile("file:/data/ProfanitySample.txt").collect()

val result = responses.map(r => {
  // using foldLeft here means we'll replace profanities one by one, 
  // with the result of each replace as the input of the next,
  // starting with the original comment 
  profanities.foldLeft(r.Comment)({ 
     case (updatedComment, profanity) => updatedComment.replaceAll(s"(?i)\\b$profanity\\b", mask) 
  })
})

result.take(10).foreach(println) // just printing some examples...
```

Note that the case-insensitivity and the "words only" limitations are implemented in the regex itself: `"(?i)\\bSomeWord\\b"`.